# How to simulate a QTreeWidget itemClicked signal without making a derived class?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qtreewidget

I am unable to find a proper simulation for ItemClicked() SIGNAL for QTreeWidget.

Is there a way to simulate it so that ItemClicked Signal is generated ?

e.g: we can emit ItemClicked in a derived class of QTreeWidget but cannot (as a QT rule) outside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `emit` call for class A to emit class B's signals.  But note that [the documentation for signals and slots](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/signalsandslots.html#advanced-signals-and-slots-usage) says:

*"You can connect as many signals as you want to a single slot, and a signal can be connected to as many slots as you need. It is even possible to connect a signal directly to another signal. (This will emit the second signal immediately whenever the first is emitted.)"*

So you can work around this by declaring a signal in class A of the same signature as the one you want class B to emit, and connecting the signals together:

```
connect(
    myclass, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)),
    treewidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int))
);
```

Then emit itemClicked from `myclass`.  If I'm not mistaken, it will work for this case...and fire the treewidget's itemClicked signal for you.

Comment: @Orochi Yup, it's weird.  The fact you *can* do this is proof that there's nothing foundational prohibiting an `emit (class instance, signal)` construct.  But this is what we've got, so...  :-/